# IIS Express exiting with code 0

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express, runas

I am running Visual Studio 2015 under an elevated account. I am working on the C: drive so I require admin permissions. So I log onto my computer with my profile, and use an elevated profile to run visual studio. Something is going wrong in the running of IIS and the web application I am trying to run.

```
Error The program '[17708] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Exit code 0 on this line alone is not an error itself. The lines before this should offer more information on what's up.

Comment: That's it. That's all I get.